# Multiple lineart silhouettes/outlines with different colors (layer order)

Tags: grease-pencil, freestyle, lineart

I would like to create Blender line art that outlines an object in black with an additional larger outline in white. When I create image 1 using Greasepencil line art and try to add a white outline by adding a second line art, the white outline obscures the black outline as seen in image 2... I can't seem to change the draw/layer/silhouette order.

Ideally, what I want is image 3 where the black silhouette of the object draws on top of a larger white silhouette.

Willing to try whatever technique/settings that works. Can someone aid me in this?

[image: A blender render showing greasepencil lineart applied to a ball]

Answer (score 3):

My question was answered for me elsewhere. The solution was to change the depth offset of the black lines under "Composition" in the modifier panel. Before I could do that, I had to uncheck the “in front” checkbox in the lineart object’s viewport display before it would give me access to “depth offset” under composition.

In my case, I also had to uncheck “in front” for my second lineart object and then tweaked the depth offset settings of both.

It works great on the ball object. However, the white did bleed through somewhat on other meshes (see the humanoid figure’s feet).

[image]

I was able to fix the white bleeding issues by using separate View Layers and combining them in the compositor. I suppose this would have also solved my original issue without needing to tweak the depth offset (but that's the correct method and using view layers is my temp hack).

[image]